# Labeling pixels in images for classification

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning

I would like to know more on how to label pixels in images. I want to use the algorithms in Caffe in order to come up with an edge detection program. So far I have filtered the image to get the edges and successfully wrote code to detect whether a pixel is an edge or not(relying on its neighboring pixels). All I want to do now is label these as edges so I can feed them as training data in my algorithm(s). I am a beginner in C++ and Caffe. What I really need is someone to explain how labeling exactly works, would I say go to every pixel It considers to be an edge and give it the value 1 for edge and 0 for non-edge ? IF so how do I do this ? References and step by step guides are well appreciated since I have been struggling for some time on this task.

Ok for example I reached this code :

```
  Mat pixelComparisonAlg(Mat img){
      Mat img_gray;
      img_gray = navigateImage(img.clone());
       for(int x=0; x < img_gray.cols-1 ; x++){
         for(int y=0; y < img_gray.rows-1; y++ ){
          Vec3b value1 = img_gray.at<Vec3b>(Point(x+1,y+1));
          Vec3b value2 = img_gray.at<Vec3b>(Point(x+1,y));
          Vec3b value4 = img_gray.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y+1));
          Vec3b value = img_gray.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));

          if( value1 != value || value != value2  ||  value!= value4){
              //EDGE!

              value.val[0] = 0;
              value.val[1] = 0;
              value.val[2] = 255;

              value1.val[0] = 0;
              value1.val[1] = 0;
              value1.val[2] = 255;

              img_gray.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = value;

          }
           else{

               value;

           }
       }
   }
   return img_gray;
 }


int main( int argc, char** argv )
  {
      Mat img = cv::imread("...", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);


   if(! img.data){
       cout << "could not open or find the image" << endl;
       return -1;
}

   imshow("edges", pixelComparisonAlg(img.clone()));






   cv::waitKey(0);
   return 0;

}
```

is there a possibility to label these pixels as edges ? Lets say I take the code that changes the colors of the edges to red(after the if statement) modify it to label the pixel as edge or not. Thus I have a vector carrying information about the pixel : color (3 vector elements) and label ( 1 vector element)

Thank you

Comment: You need to break down your problem into managable pieces. Ask yourself "how are the items (in your pixels) stored?", "how are they accessed?", "what data structure can hold the information edge / not-an-edge?", "how do I connect these two structures?". If you actually have code you understand to the things so far, I highly doubt this would be a problem for you. Otherwise, start with an easier problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it gave me a better logic to tackle this matter. I mean I have stored the pixel values in vectors to display their RGB configuration, the information is accessed through the value of every element in that vector. What data structure can hold information? I would say for each pixel there has to be another storage location, ie vector element to store the corresponding label value. so all I need to do is add another element to each vector with its label ? Thus creating a matrix for all the pixels with their corresponding labels ?

Comment: If I am understanding right the problem, I am thinking of a mask for each image, containing 1 of edges and 0 for non-edges. I am not really sure about your approach, but OpenCV has function that can find edges (like [gradinets](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html)) And based on that you can create a mask, using a [threshold function](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html).

Comment: @sop yes I have been doing a bit of research and I stumbled upon the edge detector through threshold functions. What I am trying to do is create training data for a certain supervised learning algortihm, my ultimate goal is to tweak these algorithms to produce the best results for unseen data (a good classifier). That is why I want to label edges. (makes sense ? ) so far I've read 2 whole books about this subject with little practice, so far implementing the methods has been hectic

Comment: Sounds very interesting, so what you are trying to train: a classifier/detector of edges?

Comment: @sop yes I would like to use different algorithms to test different aspects, for example Im working currently on Checkerboard recognition, to detect the edges of a checkerboard as practice. My ultimate goal is to apply these methods to classify other objects, by testing various algorithms. You can check the following website for references if you are interested in the structure of these algorithms: caffe.berkeleyvision.org. However I am hoping this would be a door for deep learning in the near future.. But as I said baby steps ;)

Comment: I should also mention I am trying to detect features and my ultimate goal is detecting features deep in the convolution layers of neural networks, which is deep learning.